# How can I close the position with open_price of next bar in pine script

Tags: pine-script

My strategy is when meeting the condition. I wil buy at close price of today and sell at open price of tommorow. I wonder how to use strategy.close() to close the position at open price of the next bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your stop loss to some extreme levels to trigger an exit as soon as the next bar opens.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop=10e16)

if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short", stop=0)
```

[image]